# Custom ComboBox control inside other custom ComboBox control, how to bind Items?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I created two custom `ComboBox` controls, both inherit from the default `ComboBox` control:

```
public BlueComboBox : ComboBox {}
public WhiteComboBox : ComboBox {}
```

`BlueComboBox` contains a template and is styled properly and works perfectly.
`WhiteComboBox` is a bit more complex. It contains a template consisting of a `TextBlock` and a `BlueComboBox`.

Incorrect snippet, but you should get the idea:

```
<ControlTemplate>
  <Grid>
    <TextBlock />
    <BlueComboBox />
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Here's the tricky part: since `WhiteComboBox` is a `ComboBox` control I would like to bind the items in `BlueComboBox` to the ones set in my `WhiteComboBox` control.

```
<WhiteComboBox>
  <ComboBoxItem Content="Foo" />
  <ComboBoxItem Content="Bar" />
</WhiteComboBox>
```

I tried binding the ItemSource of the `BlueComboBox` entity used in the template to the `ItemsSource` property of my `WhiteComboBox`, but that did not seem to work:

```
<ControlTemplate>
  <Grid>
    <TextBlock />
    <BlueComboBox ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}" />
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

What's the proper way to use the items defined in my `WhiteComboBox` instance to the `BlueComboBox` instance? Am I using the `ItemsSource` property incorrectly, or should I use another one?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a RelativeSource binding:

```
<ControlTemplate>
  <Grid>
    <TextBlock />
    <BlueComboBox ItemSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}, Path=Items}" />
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

As an aside, usual practice in WPF is to use Styles to alter visual aspects of controls, rather than creating derived types.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick.

I am using styles, but each ComboBox type contains extra DependencyProperties and since I'm fairly new at this creating my own custom controls based upon them was the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a second problem I'm experiencing with this.

I styled the ItemContainerStyle property and set a SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey value. When I use the BlueComboBox on its own this works perfectly when I hover over an item. However, when I embed my BlueComboBox in my new control this doesn't work anymore when I use the ItemsSource template binding. When I directly add some ComboBoxItems in my control template to the BlueComboBox item it works again. It also works when I explicitly click on an item.

I tried setting the ItemContainerStyle property on my WhiteComboBox control template and passing it down, but none of the things I tried seems to do the trick.